How do I limit a Google Finance formula so it only looks at the first 20 rows?
How do I limit the number of rows this formula looks at?
I only want it to return the lowest number from the first 20 rows. I don't want it to consider the rows below 20.
QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://fakewebsite.com/", "table", 1), "SELECT Col3, Col2 order by Col2 limit 1")


use the row() function and test for less than or equal to 20.

Use query() two times, first to get just the first 20 rows, then to get the one row within those 20 rows that has the smallest value in column 2, like this:
=query( 
  query( 
    importhtml("https://fakewebsite.com/", "table", 1), 
    "limit 20", 
    1 
  ), 
  "select Col3, Col2 order by Col2 limit 1", 
  1 
)

See query().

Thank you for taking time to reply. This is very helpful.

ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to limit the number of result
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://fakewebsite.com/", "table", 1), "select Col3, Col2"), 20, 2)

Please change the 3rd parameter of ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, depending on how many columns you are looking forward to get as well.
Reference: ARRAY_CONSTRAIN

Thank you for taking time to reply. Do I leave out query? Also, I need 2 columns (Col2 and Col3). How do I denote these 2 columns?

@yeto thank you for responding, please take a look at my updated answer

This will work. Thank you so very much for helping.

Thank you for responding! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
